Slack connect - what happens if I invite persons (emails) without Slack account?
What is the user journey of the invited persons in case I use Slack connect to invite external persons and these persons still dont have their slack account created (under their invited emails)?

I tried to find the information on slack help website, but haven't seen relevant answer.
